# Angular stripping dollar variable in http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to send data with an `HTTP GET` request in angular js. Below is my data:

```
 var model={
    "$or":[
    {name:'t1'},
    {createdBy:
    {
    '$ne':'t2'
    }}
    ]
    }
```

My http request object is like below:

```
    var url="abc.com/xyz";
    var request = {
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: url',
                        params: model
                    };
```

I am getting createdBy object as {} object when I inspect the request , angular is stripping that variable which has `$` in it. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: angularjs treats `$` as private.

Comment: I would construct your query on the server - just send back the info needed to construct it. No need to send a full fledged query to the server from the client, what if someone intercepts it and sends malicious code!?

Comment: I want to send it from UI in that way only. Is their any way to do that ?

Comment: Try wrapping both name and value of the JSON fields in double-quotes. In your JSON example, some fields have no wrapping `"` while others have single quote (`$ne`).

Comment: @FDavidov , I tried that also, but that too didn't work

Comment: In that case, I would concur with @tymeJV and suggest to avoid using the `$` sign as part of your variables' name.

Comment: solved, actually I was sending value of $ne as undefined and variables which have undefined values are never get sent to the server. After assigning reasonable value to $ne , it worked.